# count row duplicate values in a column sql

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I need a query to obtain following result. The aim is to count the repeated value of a column in articlecode. Also the repeated rows should be truncated or displayed.

Table_1: (Before using query)

```
processname         articlecode     articlename    stock    createdon
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9192    M/C EMB TOP PCS 2000    8/16/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9192    M/C EMB TOP PCS 6200    8/23/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9192    M/C EMB TOP PCS 4450    8/24/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9193    BACK CUT PCS    4000    8/14/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9193    BACK CUT PCS    6200    8/23/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9259    LINNING CUT PCS 4000    8/14/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9259    LINNING CUT PCS 2000    8/16/2021
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9259    LINNING CUT PCS 6200    8/23/2021
```

Table_1: (After using query, the table should look like this below)

```
processname         articlecode     articlename     stock   createdon   rown
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9192    M/C EMB TOP PCS 2000    8/16/2021   1
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9192    M/C EMB TOP PCS 6200    8/23/2021   1
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9192    M/C EMB TOP PCS 4450    8/24/2021   1
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9193    BACK CUT PCS    4000    8/14/2021   2
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9193    BACK CUT PCS    6200    8/23/2021   2
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9259    LINNING CUT PCS 4000    8/14/2021   3
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9259    LINNING CUT PCS 2000    8/16/2021   3
STITCHING PRODUCT   TH11592-9259    LINNING CUT PCS 6200    8/23/2021   3
```

i need rown colume count based on articlecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DENSE_RANK` we can try:

```sql
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY articlecode) AS rown
FROM Table_1
ORDER BY articlecode, createdon;
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. i try but my acutal requirment not meet so i re enter the data please will check and let me know how can i manage that